# Stickyfooter extra whitespace

Tags: html, css

I have employed the method found here to add a sticky footer to my client's website.

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/html-code.html

It works really well except for one instance where we have a long list of content to filter though which causes the page to shrink significantly and leaves a lot of whitespace UNDER the footer.

This can be scene by going to http://johnnycupcakes.myshopify.com/?col=all, and filtering by Gender-> Girls. You will see a ton of whitespace under the footer and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get rid of it. I have tried messing with the heights of every wrapping div i can find but have come up short.

Thanks in advance for any tips/advice!

Comment: the site looks fine to me both with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I'm getting no layout problems at all ... btw, the site looks neat.

Comment: Thanks for the props @henser but unfortunately both the client and myself are still seeing the issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Here is your problem]

Seen in firefox 3d view. Your backend is generating a bunch of blank images.

Comment: I always forget about the 3d view in firefox. Those are not "blank" images but are simply hidden based on the filters selected. They do however seem to be the culprit here. I changed them from "visibility: hidden" to display: none, but that doesn't seem to have done the trick either.